# Python: Why am I getting [Errno 13] Permission Denied?

Tags: python

I am trying to write some code that searches a group of files for a string and then places any files that include the string into a different directory which at the start of the program will not exist.

```
import os
import re

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2")
    for x in (files):
        inputFile = open((x), "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()
        if "Hello Word" in content:
            with open ("C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2", "w") as outputFile:
                outputFile.write(content)
```

When it runs I get the following error message

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2'
```

Just wondering if anyone can tell me why this error message appears.

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause of your error, but you are creating a directory then trying to open it for writing.

Comment: Also, what line is the error related to?

Comment: That'll probably be it- don't you mean to open a file in the directory?

Comment: @DavidRobinson i mean to move the file which is stored in x to the new directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot open a directory for writing:

```
os.mkdir("C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2")
```

followed by

```
open("C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2", "w")
```

won't work. Did you mean to add a filename to the latter statement?

If that was to be based on the `x` filename, you should add that name to the path:

```
with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2", os.path.basename(x)), 'w') as outputFile:
```

To *move* the file, use [`shutil.move()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) instead; no need to 'open' the directory for that:

```
if "facebook.com" in content.lower():
     shutil.move(x, "C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2")
```

Complete code, simplified:

```
def test():
    src = "C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles"
    dst = "C:/Users/David/Files/TestFiles2"
    os.mkdir(dst)
    for filename in os.listdir(src):
        path = os.path.join(src, filename)
        with open(path, "r") as inputFile:
            content = inputFile.read()
        if "facebook.com" in content.lower():
            shutil.move(path, dst)
```

Comment: i only mean to move any file that contains the strings into the new directory

Comment: @LWH91: then the above code will write a new file with the same base filename in the `FacebookFiles` directory, with the same contents.

Comment: it works, thank you. Out of interest is there not a way or moving the file without opening the directory first? like a copy from A to B thing

Comment: @LWH91: You need to *create* the directory first (that's what `os.mkdir()` does for you), but there is no need to *open* a directory at all. I simplified the `move()` call, it already detects if the destination is a directory and will move the file into that directory with the same name.

Comment: thats what i thought, how do I just copy/move the file from the first directory to the second?

Answer (score 0):

You will select all files with that if statement:

`"XXX" or "YYY" in "ZZZ"` always evaluates to True. It is the same as
`("XXX") or ("YYY" in "ZZZ")`. Since a nonempty string evaluates to True, you will select all files.

EDIT:

```
if "facebook.com" or "Facebook.com" in content:
    ...
```

It will seem like all files contain `"facebook.com"` or `"Facebook.com"`, but that's only because `"facebook.com"` in itself evaluates to True. `"Facebook.com" in content` will never even be checked. The if statement is functionally equal to

```
if "facebook.com":
    ...
```

and the if block will be executed. What you actually meant was

```
if ("facebook.com" in content) or ("Facebook.com" in content):
    ...
```

That's that. And if you don't want to search all content twice, you can use regular expressions, but that's a different topic.

Comment: i see what you mean. could you elaborate please

Comment: brilliant thanks, i was looking at regular expressions and would prefer to use them